# How to create PDF links with action "Open a file" in XSL-FO?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is there any way to specify the PDF link action "Open a file" in XSL-FO for PDF creation?

I am using the following for external files in PDF:

```
<fo:basic-link color="blue" text-decoration="underline">
    <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">externalfile.txt</xsl:attribute>
    externalfile.txt
</fo:basic-link>
```

but this code is creating a web link in PDF (icon is pointing hand with "W" inside it, PDF link action is "**Open a web link**"). I would like to know how to create PDF links with action "**Open a file**" in XSL-FO? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't it work though? If I generate that PDF it does show as a web link but clicking it does open the file. Or are you looking for something else here like embedding a document inside a PDF? Even though it shows as a W(eb) link, the path is file:///...

Comment: It works although it's a web link. I know both link actions could open the files, but for some purposes, I have to use "Open a file" for external file link. I found that [axf:action-type](https://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf3-extension.htm#axf.action-type) can specify the action of external link, but it need to use AH XSL Formatter. Apache FOP doesn't support. :(